# Listing products sold within a date range and order them by quantity sold

Tags: sql

The task is: List the products according to the quantity they were sold in winter from less to many.

I have data like below.

#### Products

| *product_code* | *product_name* |
| --- | --- |
| 3334 | AAA |
| 8388 | BBB |

#### Sales

| *sales_code* | *product_code* | sales_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5577 | 3334 | 25-12-2019 12:29 |
| 5578 | 8388 | 14-03-2020 13:30 |

#### Desired Result

| *produ_code* | *product_name* | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3334 | AAA | 55 |
| 8388 | BBB | 97 |

We know that the winter months are December, January, and February. According to the dates I have to find quantity.

I don't know how to start but

```
(WHERE sales.sales_date
   AND sales.sales_date BETWEEN '01-12- 00:00:00' AND '28-02- 00:00:00'
 GROUP 
    BY sales_products.products_id)
```

Can you help?

Comment: Please identify the DBMS you are using.  Date/time handling in particular varies between DBMS.  Your notation `'01-12- 00:00:00'` is not one I've seen before; it would be an invalid syntax in many DBMS.

Comment: You seem to manufacture the quantity sold out of thin air — none of the input tables record a quantity.  Please revise your sample data appropriately.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler i haven't a table record about Quantity. according to the sales for ex: 3334 numbered product is sold X times, like that

Comment: I see — so neither the 55 nor the 97 can be generated from the sample data shown in the question.  Both would have the value 1 for the sample data.  Each sales record counts as 1 towards the quantity.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
 SELECT a.product_code,
       a.product_name,
       count(*) as Quantity
  FROM Products a, 
       Sales b
 WHERE a.product_code = b.product_code
   AND sales.sales_date 
       BETWEEN '01-12- 00:00:00' AND '28-02- 00:00:00' 
GROUP BY a.product_code,
         a.product_name;
```

Thank you.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: I disagree. It's just the opposite

Comment: No, on RDMBS the JOIN syntax decreases comprehension about structure (index, perform, keys, ecc..)
and frequently cause the errors in the explain plain and performance.
Pehaps in NoSql DB is easier but in RDMBS is highly prohibited.

Comment: It seems like you're blaming the proper SQL syntax for some implementation issues. Which decade did you experience those issues? And which product?

Comment: Mostly Oracle (from 10g to now)  and SqlServer (from 6.0 to now).